# SymmetricDS: Merging tables from multiple nodes into a single table of another node

Tags: symmetricds

I am using a local installation of MySQL to store data across multiple schemas (`client_db_one` and `client_db_two`). Both schemas contain the table `shared_table`. However, depending on the schema the columns of this table differ.

`shared_table` looks in `client_db_one` as follows:

```
    | id | name       | column_one |
    |----|------------|------------|
    | 1  | from_tab_1 | some       |
```

`shared_table` looks in `client_db_two` as follows:

```
    | id | name       | column_two |
    |----|------------|------------|
    | 2  | from_tab_2 | other      |
```

My goal is to use SymmetricDS to synchronize these tables into a corresponding table `shared_table` in a schema `central_db` merging columns of both tables, i.e.

1. Columns should be created dynamically in `shared_table` of `central_db` if they don't exist.
2. If a dataset transferred from client_db does not contain a column specified in `shared_table` in `central_db` the corresponding value in that column should be set to NULL.

For the given example `shared_table` in `central_db` should look like:

```
    | id | name       | column_one | column_two |
    |----|------------|------------|------------|
    | 1  | from_tab_1 | some       | NULL       |
    | 2  | from_tab_2 | NULL       | other      |
```

---

So far I managed to set up a master node associated with `central_db` (also a schema in MySQL database) and two client nodes associated with `client_db_one` and `client_db_two`, using a `.properties` file in the engine directory, for each of these nodes. I successfully transferred data from each of the client nodes to the master node.

However depending on the client node that first data was transferred from, `shared_table` in `central_db` only contains columns of the client node's corresponding table. Further columns of other nodes will be omitted.

I first transferred data from `client_db_one` hence `shared_table` in `central_db` looks as follows:

```
    | id | name       | column_one |
    |----|------------|------------|
    | 1  | from_tab_1 | some       | 
    | 2  | from_tab_2 | NULL       |
```

The documentation contains a section regarding the synchronization of schema changes. However, this is not what I am looking for.

Is there a way to configure the desired synchronization without making any alteration to tables of the client schemas?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are describing via pure configuration.   You would have to write an extension point in bsh or Java to use SymmetricDS APIs to accomplish this.

Comment: Or request a feature to configure SymmetricDS table management to never drop columns (which shouldn't be too difficult to add)